# android compare closeup faces to find most similar face

Tags: android, image-processing, face-recognition

i need a library to compare input image with other images and return which one is most similar.

my images are **CloseUp Faces** !

in java I tried [javaFaces](https://code.google.com/p/javafaces/) , but i can't run it in android because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483541/using-javafaces-in-android) problem !

Comment: OpenCV may have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of OpenSource Image processing libraries

1. Fiji
2. Commons Imaging
3. ImageMagick
4. LeadTools
5. openCV

Comment: I recommend OpenCV for reasons.

Comment: thanks , is there any open source face recognizer based on openCV ?

Comment: OpenCV 2.4 now comes with the very new FaceRecognizer class for face recognition